# in Airflow, how to set logging level for the airflow-scheduler component?

Tags: airflow

I am running Airflow 2.5.2 in a docker image.

When I run it, the airflow-scheduler module spews out a huge amount of DEBUG messages to the console.  I'm trying to view the console to fix a different issue, and this stuff from airflow-scheduler is driving me nuts.

I have tried these environment variables, but none make any difference :

`AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__LOGGING_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO`

Does anyone know how to set the log level to INFO for the airflow-scheduler?   Thanks!

Comment: The correct environment variable is `AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL` ([reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#config-logging-logging-level)).

Given that you've tried that, are you sure these are Airflow logs and not third-party logs? It'd be helpful if you shared an example of the logs.

Also, if you're running Airflow in a distributed environment, make sure this env var is set on all components (e.g. scheduler, worker, etc.)

Comment: Hello RNHTTR thanks for the confirmation and reference.  I have doubled checked and I am indeed using that parameter.  As it's a docker image i'm running it is in the .env file, and all the other parameters in that file appear to work, so i'm baffled about why this parameter does not work in this situation.
Here is an example of some of the logs :

airflow-scheduler  | [2023-07-31 16:53:28,814] {scheduler_job.py:1365} DEBUG - callback is empty
airflow-scheduler  | [2023-07-31 16:53:28,844] {scheduler_job.py:355} DEBUG - No tasks to consider for execution.
airflow-scheduler  | [2023-07-31

Comment: Can you run `docker exec <container> printenv` to ensure the environment variable is actually set in the container?

Comment: Hello, yes this is the result :

docker exec 2701c72b8711 printenv | select-string LOG

AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__LOGGING_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
AIRFLOW_VAR_TENANT_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO

That is the container for airflow-scheduler container.  I can't understand why it's not applying the settings

Comment: These look like the defaults. How are you attempting to set the environment variables?